# PHP use mysql server or MS SQL server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am making a website in CORE PHP. So my question is, which database is the best for my site.ms sql server or mysql. please explain why i should choose one for another. no specific needs just want to know the cons and pros of mysql and ms sql

Comment: Ms SQL = costs $$$

Comment: Express is free up until 4GB of data (not counting logs). It may be restricted to a number of cores too.

Comment: I think it is 10GB now (doesn't say if it includes log or not). And unlike common perception Express edition can be used in production environment.  The question is, what to do when DB size goes above 10gb. Also Express is limited in features that may be necessary.  I just migrated from Asp+EF+SQL Server to Asp+EF+MySql and pretty happy about the performance and control that MySql gives you.  SQL Server licensing is based on number of cores/threads and I didn't want to pay over $60K (yes, this is correct) to have two server license (one for replication) b/c my servers are 32 threads each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using php I'd go with postgresql. Otherwise mysql because sql server doesn't always play as nice with php (need to load specific sql server drivers if on linux). If I recall, these sql server drivers weren't gonna be supported in the future.

Comment: thank you for replay me , my hosting server is also on windows so what is the best use ??

Comment: If you're on Windows I'd go with .net/sql server express over php. Have seen some odd behavior with php on windows in the past. Check out visual studio community edition